# Disable composer cache for git clone

Tags: git, composer-php

When composer tries to clone my git repo from Bitbucket, it loads it from cache. Where the latest commits from master are not loaded which results in an outdated repo. Clearing the composer cache each time seems cumbersome. 
I want to force composer to load this repo never from cache. `--prefer-source` could do the trick. But how do go about this in the best way. How to add the force no cache in the code below?

```
 "mybbrepo": {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "project/mybbrepo",
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "drupal-theme-custom",
            "source": {
                "url": "git@bitbucket.org:project/mybbrepo.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
             }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in Composer's cache - you're using incorrect type for repository. You should use `vcs` as a type:

```
"mybbrepo": {
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "git@bitbucket.org:project/mybbrepo.git"
},
```

[`package`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2) type should be used only for non-composer packages (without `composer.json` file inside) - usually you should avoid it, since it has many limitations:

> **Note**: This repository type has a few limitations and should be avoided whenever possible:
>
> - Composer will not update the package unless you change the `version` field.
> - Composer will not update the commit references, so if you use `master` as reference you will have to delete the package to force an
>     update, and will have to deal with an unstable lock file.

Comment: Do you mean the way I did it, won’t update. If I use vcs it will will update than? vcs does not need a  reference to the master than?

Comment: You should use `dev-master` as dependency constraint (when using `vcs` type), then it should update from `master` without any trouble. `package` is for static references - it will not update until you change `version` field.

Comment: Thank you for the info. How do I add dev-master as a dependency when using vcs?

Comment: You should have something like this in your `composer.json`: `"require": {"project/mybbrepo": "dev-master"}`.

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks! Added composer.json file in root of repo: `{ "name": "Your name here", "type": "drupal-module-custom", "description": "Your description here", "minimum-stability": "dev" }`.  And this in "respositories" section of  composer.json of the project `"mybbrepo": {
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "git@bitbucket.org:project/mybbrepo.git"
}` 
Now I can do `composer require project/mybbrepo.git' and set in 'require' which version I want (dev-master or any git tagged version).